Receiving Bad Request Error From Starbucks Website
I am not an expert on sending HTTP requests, so hopefully this will be an easy fix for an expert to see.
It will help to understand the overall context, which is to be able to use the Starbucks website, Starbucks.com, to obtain lists of stores. To see the issue, please go to Starbucks.com and click on "Find a store" (in the upper right). Turn on the developer tools for your browser (I am using Chrome). Enter a city into the search box. If you are using Chrome Developer Tools, click on the Network tab, then Headers, and you will see the request URL.
Starbucks Website Request
If the request is correct, the API running on that server should send back a JSON string with store info. This obviously works fine from the Starbucks website, when the browser is sending the request, but my goal is to send the request programmatically, and when I do so I am getting a Bad Request error.
I am using curl to try and figure out what works, but no luck so far. This is my curl command...
curl "https://www.starbucks.com/bff/locations?lat=46.6540153&lng=-120.5300666&place=Selah%2C%20WA%2C%20USA"
This is the response...
{"error":{"statusCode":400,"error":"Bad Request","message":"Bad Request"}}
But wait, there's more. Starbucks websites outside the US and Canada use a different API, and those request seem to work for me. You can see this by going to Starbucks UK and following the same steps above. I can send the following request to the UK site, and it works...
curl "https://www.starbucks.co.uk/api/v2/stores/?filter%5Bcoordinates%5D%5Blatitude%5D=46.65401517464598&filter%5Bcoordinates%5D%5Blongitude%5D=-120.5300666&filter%5Bradius%5D=1"
It returns...
{"data":[{"id":"1045271","type":"store","attributes":{"storeNumber":"80391-307295","name":"S. 1st \u0026 Pleasant - Selah","address":{"streetAddressLine1":"512 S 1st St","streetAddressLine2":null,"streetAddressLine3":"Suite A","city":"Selah","countrySubdivisionCode":"WA","countryCode":"US","postalCode":"989421604","countyCode":"Yakima"},"phoneNumber":"5092428533","isOpen":true,"open24x7":null,"openHours":{"monday":{"open":true,"open24Hours":false,"openTime":"04:30:00","closeTime":"20:00:00"},"tuesday":{"open":true,"open24Hours":false,"openTime":"04:30:00","closeTime":"20:00:00"},"wednesday":{"open":true,"open24Hours":false,"openTime":"04:30:00","closeTime":"20:00:00"},"thursday":{"open":true,"open24Hours":false,"openTime":"04:30:00","closeTime":"20:00:00"},"friday":{"open":true,"open24Hours":false,"openTime":"04:30:00","closeTime":"20:00:00"},"saturday":{"open":true,"open24Hours":false,"openTime":"05:30:00","closeTime":"20:00:00"},"sunday":{"open":true,"open24Hours":false,"openTime":"05:30:00","closeTime":"20:00:00"},"open24x7":false},"features":[{"code":"SE","name":"Mobile Multi Tender"},{"code":"OS","name":"Outdoor Seating"},{"code":"GO","name":"Starbucks Wi-Fi"},{"code":"DR","name":"Redeem Rewards"},{"code":"CS","name":"Caf\u00e9 Seating"},{"code":"WA","name":"Oven - Warmed Food"},{"code":"NB","name":"Nitro Brew"},{"code":"16","name":"In Store"},{"code":"DT","name":"Drive-Thru Ordering"},{"code":"XO","name":"Mobile Order and Pay"}],"coordinates":{"latitude":46.645400000000002,"longitude":-120.53084},"isOrderingAllowed":false}}]}
So what is different about the US site that my request returns Bad Request?

Even if this is not related to programming: curl --header "x-requested-with: XMLHttpRequest" "https://www.starbucks.com/bff/locations?lat=46.6540153&lng=-120.5300666&place=Selah%2C%20WA%2C%20USA" works fine

IT WORKS!
Thank you so much!

Nico mentioned this in the comment but let me add. Your curl command does not have the additional header X-Requested-With which is set to XMLHttpRequest.
curl --header "x-requested-with: XMLHttpRequest" "https://www.starbucks.com/bff/locations?lat=46.6540153&lng=-120.5300666&place=Selah%2C%20WA%2C%20USA"

This article elborates why this is required, but here is a nutshell.
The X-Requested-With header is a custom HTTP header used to indicate that the request was made via JavaScript, typically through an AJAX call rather than a traditional browser request and its value is usually set to XMLHttpRequest. This is done for a multitude of reasons for ex., to detect legitimate AJAX calls and/or add an extra layer of security against certain types of attacks etc.
